# How to transfer saved Firefox passwords into Google Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, passwords, import, export

I want to use Google Chrome more often but all my saved passwords are in Firefox.

What's the easiest way to get them into Google Chrome?

Comment: Do not use chrome to store passwords. They are stored in plain text. Please use a proper password manager that will encrypt your passwords at rest. You can get many secure password managers that will automatically work with any browser, on any OS, including mobile. No more password importing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Click the wrench icon next to the URL bar and go to *Bookmarks » Import bookmarks and settings*

Select Firefox from the drop-down menu and ensure that the "Saved Passwords" box is checked.  Finally, click import.

[image]

This topic is covered here: [Import settings from another browser - Google Chrome Help](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95418)

Comment: Unfortunately "Mozilla Firefox" does not show up as an option if you only have the portable Firefox version in use. One workaround found: Install Firefox locally, copy the user folders from portable to local, then import (as described [here](http://jimstips.com/google-chrome-tips/google-chrome-tip-2-importing-firefox-portable-bookmarks) or [here](http://superuser.com/q/630845/169199)). Other workarounds: http://superuser.com/q/271369/169199 ... PS: Why got Firefox 47 so slow... which is probably the reason for many users to move to Chrome currently.

Comment: It would be nice to have a solution where we can import "saved" saved passwords etc. from Firefox (after a refresh say) and in a folder named old*.

Comment: That is not working between Firefox 68 and Chrome 76.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that the problem is importing into Chrome passwords from
Portable Firefox, and the difficulty is that Chrome cannot detect this version
of Firefox for automatic import.

Although not having Portable Firefox, I can think of two procedures.

**Method 1 : Use LastPass on both Firefox and Chrome**

1. Install [LastPass](https://www.lastpass.com/solutions/business-password-manager)
   on Firefox, creating a LastPass login.
   LastPass will import all the Firefox passwords.
2. Install LastPass on Chrome and login to it.

Now all your passwords are available on both browsers via LastPass,
so adding a new password will also make it immediately available on the other.
LastPass also supports other browsers and devices such as smart-phones.

**Method 2 : Physically transfer from Firefox to Chrome**

1. Begin by installing LastPass on Firefox
2. Open the LastPass Vault and use *Tools > Export* to export all passwords
   into a CSV file.
   The file will have these columns which are not the correct format for Chrome:

   ```
   url,username,password,extra,name,grouping,fav
   ```
3. I used Excel as the tool to import the CSV file and transform it to the Chrome
   format and save it under a new name:

   ```
   name,url,username,password
   ```

   Note that Excel created the file with `;` characters as separators between fields,
   so I needed to use a text editor to replace them by commas.
4. Start Chrome and enter `chrome://settings/passwords`.
5. Click the three-dots button to the right of the header "Saved Passwords"
   and choose "Import".
6. Import the CSV file.
7. Done.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I was hoping for some solution that wouldn't involve any third party programs. I will consider it though if there isn't any other suggestion. Also why did you mention Firefox Portable, as far as my case I got the standard desktop app.

Comment: @ChristosK.: Portable was in some comment - an older post may include too much info. As regarding LastPass, I highly recommend it.

Comment: 'LastPass will import all the Firefox passwords' I don't think that LastPass automatically imports passwords from FF

Comment: That stopped working, but there is [a solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1363695/import-passwords-from-firefox-to-lastpass). See also the last entry in [this post](https://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=292155).

Comment: Oh come on, I am not going to use a third party solution to make another third party solution work. I mean For Firefox sake, it's about passwords after all. :) I appreciate that you are trying to help, but I think that this process should have been much easier. As a last resort I am going to write the most important passwords on a paper towel and move them around manually. :D

Comment: Well, that's computers for you, making simple things complex. If you only have a few passwords, you could just copy-paste them directly. For someone like me, with hundreds of stored passwords, this would be worthwhile.

Comment: @ChristosK.: You should decide about the bounty, because it will elapse soon.

Comment: Method 2 was working for be, but I had to enable import on chrome chrome://flags/#password-import-export

Answer (score 0):

You need this to sync your Firefox bookmarks, history, cookies and passwords with Google Chrome:

[Xmarks Bookmark Sync](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ajpgkpeckebdhofmmjfgcjjiiejpodla)

Comment: Gone now (May/April 2018). Link is dead