# Sync Firefox and Chrome passwords?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, password-management

I'm switching between Firefox and Chrome on a daily basis.
I'm tired of having to open up Firefox each time I don't remember
a Password to a website.

Is there an option to sync the saved passwords between these browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use a portable install of [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) in [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) to have all your passwords available from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks but that's unclear for me how does it collaborate with browser.

Comment: Using Auto-Type.  Hit Ctrl-Alt-A to send this sequence: username{Tab}password{Enter} to the active window.  It matches the title of the active Window with the title of your entries in Keepass.

Comment: Also works with KeePassX and Ctrl+V

Answer (score 12):

Use a plugin like [LastPass](http://lastpass.com/) that works with multiple browsers (including Firefox and Chrome).  It will take over the responsibility of storing your passwords (potentially more securely than the browsers do natively).  And it will auto-sync between systems and browsers without any additional configuration on your part.

Comment: Your answer is the one I like best -- because I use it myself. Only my password manager is Roboform. More mature than LastPass. Also works with non-web applications and on mobile devices.

Comment: Why do you say it's potentially more secure? With the plugin, security *also* depends on the plugin itself but nothing is subtracted.

Answer (score 4):

Use a password manager like LastPass.

It will generate passwords , sync automatically between all browsers and even smartphones & it is **free**. It is also very secure because it uses client side encryption using Javascript so that they never have a plain text copy of your passwords.
It can **import from Firefox and Chrome** too.

I have found LastPass to be very efficient in managing passwords. try it!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using Firefox built-in sync feature which is?

but if you are determined  to use Chrome (applicable in  version 16).

1. Chrome (Wrench) -> Settings
2. Users ->  Import Bookmarks and Settings -> select Firefox
3. **Select items to import**  has a **Saved passwords** checkbox

Comment: this is good but not for the OP's problem, because they are switching back and forth many times per day.

Comment: @endolith: you are right, i missed  the "on a daily basis"

Answer (score 0):

I think that XMarks could do the job. I know it syncs the bookmarks and browsing history. I know XMarks is available under Firefox, Chrone, Safari and IE.