# How can I transfer the contents of my portable Firefox into the installed Firefox in my laptop?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, safari, opera

I have a portable Firefox installed in my USB stick.

Also, I have the real Firefox installed in my laptop.

I usually use my Firefox portable inside my USB stick at my workplace, I know that all stuff is saved on my USB, ie: new bookmarks, new extensions, new add-ons, new histories, etc.

When I'm home, I'm always using the installed Firefox in my laptop, but how can I transfer the contents of my portable Firefox into the installed Firefox in my laptop?

Also:

1. portable Opera  transfer  ==> into the installed Opera in my laptop
2. portable Safari transfer  ==> into the installed Safari in my laptop
3. portable Chrome transfer  ==> into the installed Chrome in my laptop

Comment: There are different portable versions for Firefox and Chrome out there. Can you link the websites where you usually download them? Thats important to determine the profile path to those portable browsers.

Comment: I just downloaded all my portable browsers from PortableApps.com I remember. But can you tell me where should I downloaded from? What site is the best to get portable browsers from? Are portable browsers from different sites were created by different people? I want the genuine ones, meaning, the ones that came from the real creator.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways you can accomplish this:

1. Use [Firefox Sync](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-sync-take-your-bookmarks-and-tabs-with-you)

   [Firefox Sync](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-sync-take-your-bookmarks-and-tabs-with-you) will allow you to easily sync all your history, cookies, passwords, addons, etc. between your two firefox installations. This will also however always keep their states the same. If you just want a one time copy, you can setup Firefox Sync, allow the service to sync, then go to

   ```
   Options > Sync > Unlink This Device
   ```

   Chrome has a similar service for syncing browser states through Google accounts.
2. Firefox Profiles

   A Firefox profile is everything Firefox uses to load the browser experience for you. If you create a new profile and load Firefox with that, it will be like you've just installed Firefox anew. The profile management for Firefox is a little hidden away, but you can easily get to it by closing all Firefox windows, opening the run prompt (Windows Key + R, or just open the terminal on Linux/Mac), and type

   ```
   firefox -profilemanager
   ```

   You can also load an already made Firefox profile (like the profile on your Portable Firefox installation) with the following command:

   ```
   firefox -profile "path_to_profile"
   ```

   Replace "path_to_profile" with whatever path you copied your Portable Firefox profile to. Keep in mind that this also only works when all Firefox windows are closed first.

   According to the Firefox Portable FAQ your can find your Firefox profiles in the following path:

   ```
   C:\Documents and Settings\[user]\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\default.???\
   ```

   And you can find your Firefox Portable profile in:

   ```
   FirefoxPortable\Data\profile
   ```

Comment: +1 Thats the way to go. maybe you could also add a CMD batch (xcopy or robocopy) example for easier `External » Internal` copying?

Comment: @ Nixda: Yeah, how to do that xcopy and robocopy, External to Internal copying, and vice versa? Like transferring stuffs from Installed Browser in my laptop in the morning to my Portable Browser, then transferring back in the evening the other way around.. Thanks..

Comment: @Askto Gainknowledge: If your portable Firefox is on a USB drive you can setup the batch script to be run with autorun. You can run xcopy as such:    
  **xcopy source_folder destination_folder /s /e /h /y**  

  This will cause xcopy to copy all subdirectories, copy hidden files, and not warn you when you overwrite files. You can see all he options on [Microsoft's website](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true).