# Import passwords from Firefox to LastPass

Tags: firefox, passwords, lastpass

All of my passwords are stored in Firefox. Now I want to start using LastPass, so naturally I want to import all passwords.

For whatever reason, (a) Firefox doesn't present an option to export passwords and (b) LastPass doesn't present an option to import from Firefox.

Am I missing something? Seems obvious to me that both features should exist.

Answer (score 7):

#### Firefox doesn't present an option to export passwords

You can use [ff-password-exporter](https://github.com/kspearrin/ff-password-exporter) to export passwords:

- CSV or JSON formats.
- GPL 3.0 licensed.
- Runs on Windows, macOS, and Linux.
- Firefox 58+ with key4.db profiles is supported.

LastPass will import CSV files.

Answer (score 5):

I could not get LastPass to import the CSV that `ff-password-exporter` wrote.
Got the passwords, but none of the site URLs.

[Edit: LastPass has been updated, and should now work with Genric CSVs]

However I did find that the current Firefox (81.0.2) has an export function

1. Pull down the Firefox menu
2. Click "Logins and Passwords"
3. At the far right, is a 3-dot menu icon, pull that down
4. Select "Export Logins"
5. Install the LastPass add-on
6. Click add on `->` Account Options `->` Advanced `->` Import
7. Select source as "Generic CSV File"
8. Choose the file you just created
9. Click Upload

Comment: Just a small modification. Lastpass got updated and now the import function is under
Account options -> Advanced -> Import and then choose "Generic CSV"